# HTML/CSS Background color behind text word wrap

Tags: html, css, text, word-wrap

I'm not exactly sure how to explain this, but I created this JSFiddle to show the issue.

```css
.news {
    float: left;
    width: 465px;
    height: 260px;
    padding: 0px 7px;
    position: relative;
}
.news .news-title {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.news .news-title h2 {
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #010101;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.news img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="news">
    <div class="news-title"><h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h2></div>
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22433338/news_mc.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="news">
    <div class="news-title"><h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h2></div>
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22433338/gmod_news.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Basically, at the very end of the first line it doesn't do any padding on the right side and on the 2nd line the left side has no padding at all.

I tried using stuff like word-wrap and white-space, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: What is the desired result? One block as background, or should it only cover the width of the text?

Comment: maybe you need to add line-height: 3;

Comment: it all depends on what the original design

Comment: remove display: inline in .news .news-title h2 { class your code will work fine I think no need to to extra efforts

Comment: This is the intended design. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22433338/intendeddesign.jpg It's almost what I want, but the padding is lacking from the end of the 1st line and from the beginning of 2nd line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out

http://jsfiddle.net/mGQG4/18/

Essentially you do two things within h2 CSS

```
padding: 10px 0; /* change horizontal padding to 0 */
box-shadow: 10px 0 0 red, -10px 0 0 red; /* add this line */
```

Should work as requested. Of course, change color from red to #010101 as well.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

here's an update,
check, [Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/mGQG4/10/)

just add

```
box-shadow: 10px 0 0 black, -10px 0 0 black;
```

to **.news .news-title h2**

Comment: That fixes the padding issue, but the 2nd line's text is more at left than the 1st line. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Change line 23 to padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px; (delete the line padding:10px; and change)

Answer (score 1):

For HTML / markdown you can use:

```html
<mark style="background-color: blue; color:red;">Test-Driven Development (TDD)</mark>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to add `line-height: 3;`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mGQG4/9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use box-shadow to achieve the desired result.
Remember to modify the padding on h2 and remove the horizontal padding there.

**CSS**

```
.news {
    float: left;
    width: 465px;
    height: 260px;
    padding: 0px 7px;
    position: relative;
}
.news .news-title {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    margin: 10px 20px;
}
.news .news-title h2 {
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #010101;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    display: inline;
    line-height:220%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    box-shadow: 10px 0 0 black, -10px 0 0 black;
}
.news img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/mGQG4/27/

Comment: That's not the issue I'm having. I know the line-height has to be added to fix that. The issue is this the lack of padding on the right and left side of the break line. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22433338/issue.png

Comment: I guess i was late for this one :)

Answer (score 0):

move the background from ".news .news-title h2" to ".news .news-title" ;-)

Comment: That just makes the entire background black, even the space without text.

Comment: RevanProdigalKnight had another solution in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24757590/3022387 .. which basically does the same. The only way to get the 2nd-line container to **NOT** be just as wide as the 1st-line you'll have to seperate them semantically. Or you use **NBSP**s to pad it out .. :-( .. like so: "sit&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;amet"

Answer (score 0):

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/mGQG4/11/)

```
I can see padding between images and texts on those images.
line-height: 40px;
```

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as [Yogesh Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1273446/yogesh-sharma) pointed out in a comment, is that you have `display:inline` in your `.news .news-title h2` class. If you remove that, it works fine.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mGQG4/14/)

Comment: That's not what I want. Here's an image of what I'm trying to get. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22433338/intendeddesign.jpg It's almost what I want, but the padding is lacking from the end of the 1st line and from the beginning of 2nd line.